# Next.js "use client" & useState Unhandled Runtime Error: TypeError: __webpack_require__.n is not a function

Tags: webpack, next.js, react-hooks, typeerror, next.js13

Using React/Next.js for a simple website project. Working within a nav component with the following code:

.

```
'use client';
import { useState } from 'react';

// Imports
import { FaBars } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { FaDiscord } from 'react-icons/fa'

// NavBar Component
export function NavBar() {

  const [mobileMenuOpen, setMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false)

  return (

    <nav className="navbar flex flex-row justify-between">

      <button
        type="button"
        className="text-lg font-medium text-center p-6 hover:yellow-hover"
        onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(true)}
      >
      <FaBars />
      </button>
      
      

      <a href="#"
        className="text-lg font-bold text-center p-6 hover:yellow-hover">
        〔 sTGS 〕
      </a>
      
      <a href="#"
        className="text-lg font-medium text-center p-6 hover:yellow-hover">
        <FaDiscord />
      </a>

    </nav>

  );
}
```

.

**Getting the following error on the webpage:**

.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: __webpack_require__.n is not a function. (In '__webpack_require__.n(react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__)', '__webpack_require__.n' is undefined)
Call Stack
eval

[native code]
(app-pages-browser)/./components/navbar.jsx

/_next/static/chunks/app/page.js (28:5)
<unknown>

file:///Users/d369/Projects/websites/stgs/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (704:35)
__webpack_require__

/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:37)
```

.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccmvt.png)

.

Trying to make a mobile menu that's available on small screens. The button/icon is within my NavBar component in a React/Next.js project, which requires {useState} and "use client" in order for the component to be interactive. However, when I add either of them, I get the stated error. I've gone through the docs, YouTube, and here on Stack. Not finding any reasons why it's doing this.

How on earth do I fix this?

Comment: **This bug happens in safari**. You can use other browser. Or clear the browser cache in safari. Sorry, just summarizing for people with low attention span.

Answer (score 5):

So this one is infuriating. I have been having the same problem, first noticed yesterday. I say infuriating because it is not consistently happening.

First, I was able to replicate this runtime error with your code in a test project. I found the issue occurred not just in your component but also in my own unrelated test component.

Second, I noticed that executing

```
npm run build
npm run start
```

did not reproduce the runtime error in your component nor in my test component.

Next, I removed your component and ran in dev mode

```
npm run dev
```

which suddenly worked without the runtime error. So I added your component back and viola, the runtime error returned in both our components.

Next, I cleared the browser cache which is "Empty Caches" in Safari in the "Develop" tab or in MSFT Edge browsing to 'edge://settings/clearbrowserdata'

After a number of restarts and tests with both browsers, I was not able to reproduce the runtime error. However, when I added a third component (essential a duplicate of my test component) the same Unhandled Runtime Error returned (in just Safari). In this case, clearing the cache cleared the error (independent caches so not surprising.)

I would not call this a "solution" per se, but I am hoping that some of this information might trigger some insight by someone more talented. At a minimum it is a possible work around.

Comment: thanks! i'll empty the cache and see what happens.  i've changed the code, but still getting the same problem whenever trying to add 'use client'. have no idea what i'm doing wrong. hopefully the cache trick works for now so i can make some progress.

Comment: Clearing cache also seems to be working for me, what an infuriating error!

Comment: Same, issue, clearing cache resolved 

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add my two cents here. @Richard Beeson described my experience exactly. Also when I removed the import useState and the hook itself, the problem went away.

Although my solution was a bit different. Deleting my browser caches didn't do anything. Just like @Richard Beeson my production build had no errors while running but running dev server did. As such, along with the useState pecularities I tried deleting node modules, .next folder etc. Didn't work.

In the end it was because of my use of path aliases, in my case I have an src folder and was using the path alias "@/*" as an alias for "./src/*".  Removing the path alias and converting all the "@/*" to typical path resolution of "../../foldername" seemed to do the trick.

Also I should note I am using Next.js 14 with Node v20.10.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually in response to @Michael Chan's answer, though hopefully it helps others. Disclaimer: I'm still new to Next.js & stackoverflow so I'm very sorry for the messy syntax. I wrote this off the top of my head.

I encountered the same issue (Next 14 Node 18) of "TypeError: **webpack_require**.n is not a function". I was importing a client component into a server component, which is not feasible in Next.js (<-- my mistake). For example, doing something such as this:

ClientComponent.ts:

```
`"use client";

export const TestFunction(Data) {
// Process raw data...
return ProcessedData };`
```

ServerComponent.tsx:

```
import { TestFunction } from "@/ClientComponent.ts";

export const ServerComponent = () => {

const rd = "RawData";
const t = TestFunction(rd); // The code breaks here and calls an error because you are directly calling a function from a client side file into a server side one.

return <div>
<div>{/* Child component that displays or manipulates processed data, t. */}</div>
</div>
};
```

So the issue could be something like you're attempting to share data between a client and server component in a way that is not allowed (in a way that is too direct). In that case, the solution would be to further wrap the function/object that you want to use in another client component, and pass data into that client component via prop drilling.

Wrapped Solution:

ClientComponent.ts:

```
`"use client";

export const TestFunction(Data) {
// Process raw data...
return ProcessedData };`
```

ClientComponentWrapper.ts:

```
"use client";

import { TestFunction } from "@/ClientComponent.ts";

export const ClientComponentWrapper = (props) => {

const rd = props;
const t = TestFunction(rd); // No more errors because its called within a client component, aka note the use of "use client". The prop drilling allows the data to be interactively manipulated in a client component, something that can't be done server side.

return (<div>{/* Child component that displays or manipulates processed data, t. */}</div>);
```

ServerComponent.tsx:

```
export const ServerComponent = () => {

const rd = "RawData";

return (<div><ClientComponentWrapper props={rd} /></div>)
};
```

If you're having a similiar issue as this, hopefully it helps! And if I messed anything up, please correct me as I'm still new to Next.js and would appreciate a better explanation/correction too!